# Wordpress delete query not woking

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to delete photos from table.When I am trying deleting it on same file shows me "Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_activation_hook()" message. Also tried on another file but can't fix it.

```
  <?php
function delete(){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "test";
$id=$_GET['id'];
if($id){
$delete = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $wpdb->$table_name WHERE id = %d",$id));
 }  
 } ?>
```

Comment: have you used register_activation_hook which is used to execute function on activate plugin. If so then please send same code.

Comment: function keywords_ranker_install() {
global $wpdb;
global $keyword_rankerdb;
$keyword_rankerdb = "1.0";
$table_name       = $wpdb->prefix . "test";
if ( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'" ) != $table_name ) {
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' . $table_name . ' (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id))';
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'keywords_ranker_install' );

@WisdmLabs please have a look. Don't mind the codes aren't in right format.

Comment: @WisdmLabs Please help and let mek now if anything needed.

Answer (score 0):

The $table_name is getting its value hence no need to write "$wpdb->$table_name"

```
<?php
  function delete(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "test";
    $id=$_GET['id'];
      if($id){
         $delete = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id = %d",$id));
       }  
} ?>
```

Another way to delete photos is by wp_delete_post as in wordpress photos i.e media are saved as post.

```
<?php wp_delete_post( $postid, true); ?>
```

second parameter is set to delete image forcefully

Answer (score -2):

Try this out. I have previously used it in one of my plugins

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#DELETE_Rows

```
$wpdb->delete( $table, $where, $where_format = null );
```

As an example:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
    $where = array( 'event_id' => $event_id);  // $where part
    $where_format = array( '%d'); // $where_format
    $wpdb->delete( $table, $where, $where_format );
?>
```